# When to use Vertical Slice or Clean Architecture when developing a REST API?

Tags: architecture, clean-architecture

There are many ways to build a REST API.

Two of these ways are using [Vertical Slice](https://jimmybogard.com/vertical-slice-architecture/) and [Clean Architecture](https://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html).

In your opinion when to use Vertical Slice or Clean Architecture to build APIs?

Comment: A REST API is the interface to a system, not the underlying system itself.  Clean architecture, etc, is about architecting systems - which may or may not have an API.

Answer (score -3):

So "Vertical Slice" is basically saying "architecture is too hard, and I don't want to".  Which is a perfectly reasonable approach for certain scale of application/problem.

If you have simple enough needs, just hacking something together is perfectly reasonable, and establishing a domain layer is a complete waste of time/energy/money.

If however, you have multiple developers working on a problem, have any complex rules that you need to enforce across "slices", want to re-use your code in a different context/application, then you embrace architecture to set boundaries on how you build your application.  Clean Architecture is a culmination of decades of experience building large, complex solutions.  It can apply at both the monolith, and at the micro-service scale.

I'm not saying you need it for your "hello world" app, it makes no sense there, and adds only overhead, but calling Vertical Slice an architecture when it is just a rejection of architecture is inaccurate at best.  It may be popular with consultants that have write-once read-never code, but the rest of us have to support systems down the road and understand that humans work in abstractions and need to be able to understand what an application *does* a week after the check clears.

tldr; use "vertical slice" for toys, use clean architecture (or MVC, hexagonal, onion, etc) for solutions.

Comment: I'm down voting because this answer is opinion based. Vertical architectures should be used by people that know their stuff. I personally think clean solves problem that do not need solving and to make things worse will make the vertical slices more closely coupled than they should, while losing cohesion at the same time, the exact opposite of vertical slices. Here is an article against (although the example repo he used is pretty bad) https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/11/15/screaming-architect/

Comment: The question literally was "In your opinion when to use Vertical Slice or Clean Architecture to build APIs?" Of course it's opinion based, it asked "In your opinion".